# On French Stack Overflow Careers the Try Stack Overflow button is misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

Go to [Stack Overflow careers login page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one?referrer=topnavigation&forcenew=False), scroll down and select French as the language.

The words Essayer Stack Overflow are outside the button because the button is not in the right place.

[image: Essayer Stack Overflow]

Tried Chrome and Firefox with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css has been corrected.

Thanks for your report!